# Traverse JSON with nested property when index are in a list - python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Is there a way to traverse a JSON when the index are in a list in Python.

JSON:

```
{
 "id" : "abc",
"Obj1":
    {
        "Obj1":{
             "Name" : "123456789"
             }
    }
}
```

Conventionally we can access JSON index as:

```
data['Obj1']['Obj1']['Name'] >>Output is 123456789
```

But how to traverse this and change the value in same 'data' json object if the index are in a list like:

```
['Obj1','Obj1','Name']
```

Need a way to traverse to the location by using list in place of hard code index.

I need to replace the value also with 'XYZ' so final json should be "{ "id" : "abc", "Obj1": { "Obj1":{ "Name" : "XYZ" } } }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce` with `dict.get`:

```
from functools import reduce
path = ['Obj1','Obj1','Name']
print(reduce(lambda a, b: a[b], path, data))
```

This returns: `123456789`

If you need to assign a new value `'XYZ'` to the dict at the given path, you would then need to do it at a level above the leaf:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a[b], path[:-1], data)[path[-1]] = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i need to change the value in the original json object then?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. won't evaluating `reduce(dict.get, path, data)` again do?

Comment: I mean from reduce I will get the value but I need to replace the value also with 'XYZ' so final json should be "{ "id" : "abc", "Obj1": { "Obj1":{ "Name" : "XYZ" } } }"

Comment: Hi Just noticed if the element is an List this fails.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more general solution then.